# Migrate from Jasmine 1.3 to 2.0 with karma

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'd like to migrate an AngularJS project from Jasmine 1.3 to 2.x.

After some (solved) peer-version problems with modules `karma`, `karma-jasmine` and `grunt-karma`, I encounter additional problems.

Command line: `grunt karma:unit`

```
Fatal error: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

My questions:

- do I have to change karma.conf.js when upgrading to Jasmine 2.x?
- Is Jasmine 2 + karma working reliable or is it better to stay with 1.3 at the moment?
- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you install karma-jasmine20? Please see https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine#jasmine-20-docs

Comment: @lena, no, I installed `karma-jasmine@0.3.2`, but thought it was 0.2.0. That's the problem - karma-jasmine >= 0.3.0 needs `jasmine-core`. Thanks for the docs link!